# Different results with Laravel Lazy Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

In Laravel, what is the difference between these two function calls?

```
$this->load(['episodes.item.cast' => function ($q) use (&$cast) {
    $cast = $q->get()->groupBy("id");
}]);
```

and

```
$cast = $this->load('episodes.item.cast')->get()->groupBy("id");
```

They produce different results but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `$this` is already existing object (because You use `load` on it). By existing I mean `$this->exists => true`.

And the point there. First query is just OK, but really strange. But second is not OK at all. With using `->get()` on existing object, You create new empty query and get all values.

So basically, if You already queried for object `$obj = YourModel::find(1)` for example, and then executed `$obj->get()` You will get same result as `YourModel::all()`.

Comment: Okay. So the first query gives the result that I want but in a strange way. How could I rewrite it but still get the same results? What makes it "strange"?